# Ubuntu One saved after hard drive wiped?

Tags: ubuntu-one, hard-drive, mac, macbook-pro

I am pretty sure the answer is "yes" to this question, but I felt I had to ask anyway. If I am using Ubuntu One for Mac, and my hard drive might be wiped, will Ubuntu One keep the files I synced most recently before my computer got wiped?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The short answer and maybe the only one is "Yes".

But... We must consider that the backup on your Ubuntu One cloud will be limited to the storage space available for your account. Usually 5GB unless you upgraded your account. So, if your U1 folder and the additional synced folders exceeds that amount, the files won't be backed up.

Good luck!